# React-Redux Redux Action getting called multiple Times

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to React-Redux and I have a problem with one of my redux action objects. When I print my function this.handleUserByID(1) @KeyboardPage.jsx to console everything gets called multiple times and I recieve this error:
[image: Error_User_BYID]

But I still get the right result in the console at some point:

[[image: success_USER_BYID2]

Here my Code:

**KeyboardPage.jsx**

```
class KeyboardPage extends React.Component {

componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getTopics(2);
}

handleUserByID(user_id){
    return this.props.getUser(user_id);
}

render() {

    const { topics } = this.props;
    const { user, users} = this.props;

    console.log(this.handleUserByID(1));

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <NavBar loggedinAs={user.user_name}/>
            <h1>Gruppe 1 - Webforum</h1>
            <h3>Topics :</h3>
            {topics.loading && <em>Loading topics...</em>}
            {topics.error && <span className="text-danger">ERROR: {topics.error}</span>}
            {topics.items && users.items &&
            <ul type='none' >
                {topics.items.map((topic, index) =>
                    <li key={topic.topic_id}>
                        <p/>
                        <a href={"/" + topic.topic_id} style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
                            <TopicCard topicSubject={topic.topic_subject} topicDate={topic.topic_date} topicBy={this.handleUserByID(topic.topic_by).user_name}/>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                )}
            </ul>
            }

        </div>
    );
}
}


function mapState(state) {
    const {topics } = state;
    const { users, authentication } = state;
    const { user, } = authentication;
    return { user, users, topics};
}

const actionCreators = {
    getTopics: topicActions.getAllbyID,
    getUser: userActions.getById
}

const connectedKeyboardPage = connect(mapState, actionCreators)(KeyboardPage);
export { connectedKeyboardPage as KeyboardPage };
```

**users.reducer.js**

```
export function users(state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case userConstants.GETBYID_REQUEST:
            return {
                loading: true, id : action.id
            };
        case userConstants.GETBYID_SUCCESS:
            return {
                item: action.user
            };
        case userConstants.GETBYID_FAILURE:
            return {
                error: action.error
            };
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

**user.service.js**

```
function getById(id) {
const requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: authHeader()
};

return fetch(`${config.apiUrl}/users/${id}`, requestOptions).then(handleResponse);
}
```

**user.actions.js**

```
function getById(id) {

    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(request(id));

        userService.getById(id)
            .then(
                user => dispatch(success(user)),
                error => dispatch(failure(error.toString()))
            );
    };

    function request(id) { return { type: userConstants.GETBYID_REQUEST, id} }
    function success(user) { return { type: userConstants.GETBYID_SUCCESS, user } }
    function failure(error) { return { type: userConstants.GETBYID_FAILURE, error } }
}
```

**root reducer**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import { authentication } from './authentication.reducer';
import { registration } from './registration.reducer';
import { users } from './users.reducer';
import { categories } from './categories.reducer';
import { topics } from './topics.reducer';
import { alert } from './alert.reducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    authentication,
    registration,
    users,
    categories,
    topics,
    alert
});

export default rootReducer;
```

**EDIT:** I found a way to solve the problem. In my component KeyboardPage.jsx I already retrieved all the users. I I now simply filter the users directly according to the userId. Not the most elegant solution, but it works for now.

```
        {topics.items && users.items &&
        <ul type='none' >
            {topics.items.map((topic, index) =>
                <li key={topic.topic_id}>
                    <p/>
                    <a href={"/" + topic.topic_id} style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
                        <TopicCard topicSubject={topic.topic_subject} topicDate={topic.topic_date} topicBy={users.items.filter(user => user.user_id === topic.topic_by)[0].user_name}/>
                    </a>
                </li>
            )}
        </ul>
        }
```

Comment: It might be because you are doing it in the `render` method. Can you try to do that log inside the `componentDidMount`?

Comment: Okay, thanks first of all. When I put it in the componentDidMount it works perfectly. But I have to use it in the return method @<TopicCard topicBy={here}/> . Also how can I access the user's name ?

Comment: Why do you need to explicitly call it on the render method? That's incorrect since the function will be called every single time the component re-renders. About the user's name, assuming you did everything right with the `connect`, you should be able to access with `this.props.user.name_property`

Comment: The user id that I need for the function is changing on each iteration across all topics. Is there a way I can define it in the componentdidMount in general and call it from the render method?

Comment: No, once again, no way it is going to work on the render method. If it's something that changes you can use the `componentDidUpdate` method to detect changes in the props and with that call that function when needed

Comment: I can't really find a way to do that

Comment: Why do you need to call that function? Does this component unmounts or not? If it does you can use componentMount, if not use componentDidUpdate. Check the official documentation in React’s site